# Find the range of $f:\ (0,\infty)\ \longrightarrow\ \mathbb{R}:\ x\ \longmapsto\ \sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm having trouble with this easy exercise:

> Find the range of $f:\ (0,\infty)\ \longrightarrow\ \mathbb{R}:\ x\ \longmapsto\ \sin(\frac{1}{x}).$

I can't analyse the domain of the inverse because $f$ is not invertible, and I don't know how to restrain the domain for it to be. I tried this:

If $y$ is such that:

$y = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$

$\arcsin(y) = \frac{1}{x}$

$\frac{1}{\arcsin(y)} = x$

Then there are $x$ in this form for $y$.

But when $x>0$, $y \in (0,\infty)$, while the image was supposed to be $[-1,1]$.

I tried also using continuity, but $(0,\infty)$ is not a compact set...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The range does not mean the "domain of the inverse" (unless the function is invertible which, as you say, it isn't). The range of the function is the set of all of its values, in this case $$\text{range}(f) = \{\sin\bigl(\frac{1}{x}\bigr) \mid x \in (0,\infty)\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ as a composition of the functions
$$g:\ (0,\infty)\ \longrightarrow\ (0,\infty):\ x\ \longmapsto\ \frac{1}{x}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad h:\ \Bbb{R}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}:\ x\ \longmapsto\ \sin(x).$$
What is the range of $h(x)$? What does this tell you about the range of $h(g(x))$?

Comment: The range of $h$ is $[-1,1]$ even when $h$ is restricted to positive values, then the range of $h \circ g$ will be also $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

you know that the range must lie within $[-1,1] = \sin([2\pi,4\pi]) $, right ?

and you have for $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

$$g([\frac{1}{4\pi},\frac{1}{2\pi}] \subset (0,\infty)) = [2\pi,4\pi] $$

I'm sure you know how to conclude.

Comment: Then range of $\sin \circ g$ will be equal to $\sin([2\pi,4\pi]) = [-1,1]$